# React useMutation doesn't pass the correct parameters input

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-server

I'm trying to execute a Mutation in a project, where I have Appollo GraphQL as middleware and reactJS as a front-end.

I have the following schema (the idea is to send a contact form):

```
input entryIntput {
        url_title: String!
        title: String!
        channel_id: Int!
        entry_date: String!
        name: String!,
        motivation: String!
        mail: String!
        job_position: String
    }
...
type Mutation {
        createEntry(input: entryIntput): postEntrySuccess
    }
```

Resolvers:

```
  Mutation: {
    createEntry: (_, { input }) => channelEntriesService.postEntry(input)
  }
```

ChannelEntriesService:

```
    url_title: 'Application Form Entry-',
    title: 'Application Form Entry #',
    entry_date: Date.now(),
    channel_id: 3
  }) {
    const auth = await authenticate.auth()
    const nextEntry = await this.getNextEntry();

    const patch = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      url: `${this._options.url}/create_channel_entry`,
      data: `channel_id=${entry.channel_id}&url_title=${entry.url_title}${nextEntry}&title=${entry.title} ${nextEntry}&name=${entry.name}&motivation=${entry.motivation}&job_position=${entry.job_position}&mail=${entry.mail}&entry_date=${entry.entry_date}&session_id=${auth.session_id}`
    }

    const response = await axios(patch);

    return response.data;
  }
```

I have the Queue execution via `useMutation` and declaration like:

```
    const APPLY = gql`
      mutation PostEntry($input: entryIntput) {
        createEntry(input: $input) {
          entry_id
        }
      }
    `;
....
  const [createEntry, { error: formError, loading: formLoading }] = useMutation(APPLY);
```

On the front-end, where I'm using React-Hook-Form:

```
  const onSubmit = (applicantData) =>
    createEntry({
      variables: {
        url_title: applicantData?.name?.trim(),
        entry_date: Date.now(),
        title: applicantData?.name,
        ...applicantData,
      },
    });
```

When I execute the submit I've got **undefined** for the **entry** param in my channelEntries
.postEntry(),

```
While I execute it through a mutation from the apollo studio like: 
mutation applicationEntryForm($entryInput: entryIntput) {
  createEntry(input: $entryInput) {
    entry_id
  }
}

query_variables: 
{
  "entryInput": {
    "channel_id": 3,
    "url_title": "my First Entry input",
    "entry_date": "1623829177995",
    "title": "Voila intruder!",
    "name": "Vlad",
    "job_position": "cleaner",
    "motivation": "My motivation notes",
    "mail": "vlado@vlado1.com"
  }
}
```

it has the correct parameters and an entry is created successfully.
What I'm doing wrong in the front-end "useMutation" and the submit function where the variables need to be passed?

I think you very much in advance for reading this and giving me some tips as I'm really stacked :(

Comment: start with ... `createEntry({ variables: { entryInput <<<<<` ... later, check request body in dev tools/network

Comment: Changing the property name under variables to entryInput gives the same undefined value for a passed parameter though. Also good advice on inspecting the header request: it is for some reason without parameters: 
`operationName: "postEntry"
query: "mutation postEntry($createEntryInput: entryIntput) { createEntry(input: $createEntryInput) {  entry_id  __typename  }}"
variables: {}`

Comment: next variable renaming? type [and input types] names usually starts with uppercased char (PascalCase) - easier to recognize props/vars vs types ... prepare and log entire `variables` before passing to mutation invoker (`createEntry`) ... form data handling problem? show all form [and data/state] related component code

Answer (score 0):

After renaming some of the variables as [@xadm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6124657/xadm) mentioned I found the following:

there is a difference when I use:

```
  const [createEntry, { error: formError, loading: formLoading }] = useMutation(APPLY);
```

and

```
  const [createEntry, { error: formError, loading: formLoading }] = useMutation(APPLY, {});
```

e.g. passing an empty object for the options parameter actually makes things happening.

Comment: does it really make a difference on network request body (browser dev tools)? show it

Comment: It seems so, I'll try one more time without the options parameter.